# Is "==" in Ruby always value equality?

Tags: ruby, string-comparison, object-comparison

Sorry if duplicated (I didn't find it)

This is only to confirm that Ruby's operator `==` performs always an equality comparison.
I.e.

```
a == b
```

compares a's value against b's value, instead than, like Java, whether they point to the same object in memory (For this latter thing, in Ruby, you should use `a.object_id == b.object_id`).

Thus, as a consequence it is safe to compare string values with == in Ruby (while it is not safe to do so in Java)

Thanks

**Edit**:

The question is on the the default == behavior for any Ruby object, as it can mislead Java-C-C++ programmers assuming a==b compares references themselves, not the reference contents.

Anyway,  you can check out this code, using strings

```
one="hello"
two="he"
two << "llo"

if one == two
  puts "surprise: comparing values, not like in Java"
end

if not one.object_id == two.object_id
  puts "obvious: do this to compare references"
end
```

**Edit 2**.

So, in Ruby, the comparison

```
a == b
```

checks  a's and b's values

but, the assignment

```
a = b
```

does not copy values, but makes a and b point to the same object !

continuing with the previous code

```
puts one.object_id
puts two.object_id

puts " and now "

one = two

puts one.object_id
puts two.object_id
```

Comment: Yes.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710369/most-concise-way-to-test-string-equality-not-object-equality-for-ruby-strings

Comment: The referenced link is not a duplicate of this question...

Comment: Yes the first thing i realized is that in Ruby the operator `==` and the function `equals` are inverted to what it is expected in C like languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, `==` can be overloaded, so it could do anything the designer of the class you're comparing wants it to do. In that respect, it's very similar to Java's `equals()` method.

The convention is for `==` to do value comparison, and most classes follow that convention, `String` included. So you're right, *using `==` for comparing strings will do the expected thing.*

The convention is for `equal?` to do reference comparison, so your test `a.object_id == b.object_id` could also be written `a.equal?(b)`. (The `equal?` method could be defined to do something nonstandard, but then again, so can `object_id`!)

(Side note: when you find yourself comparing strings in Ruby, you often should have been using symbols instead.)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/.

**The code:**

```
class MyObject
end
object1 = MyObject.new
object2 = object1
object3 = MyObject.new

puts "Object 1 is == to object 2: #{object1 == object2}"
puts "Object 1 is eql? to object 2: #{object1.eql? object2}"
puts "Object 1 is equal? to object 2: #{object1.equal? object2}"
puts "Object 1 is == to object 3: #{object1 == object3}"
puts "Object 1 is eql? to object 3: #{object1.eql? object3}"
puts "Object 1 is equal? to object 3: #{object1.equal? object3}"
```

**The output:**

```
Object 1 is == to object 2: true
Object 1 is eql? to object 2: true
Object 1 is equal? to object 2: true
Object 1 is == to object 3: false
Object 1 is eql? to object 3: false
Object 1 is equal? to object 3: false
```

**Edit - Additional output:**

```
irb(main):001:0> class MyObject
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> object1 = MyObject.new
=> #<MyObject:0x281bc08>
irb(main):006:0> object1.respond_to?( '=='.to_sym )
=> true
irb(main):007:0> object1.respond_to?( 'eql?'.to_sym )
=> true
irb(main):013:0> MyObject.superclass
=> Object
```

Comment: This is misleading, because `MyObject` doesn't define any of these methods properly.

Comment: By "properly" I mean "according to convention", which is: `equal?` does reference equality, `eql?` does value equality, and `==` does value equality with type conversions. The article that the above was ripped from (http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/) explains this well, but just this code lacks the context that actually answers the question.

Comment: I disagree... unless it is overridden, that is how every object will work - the code is self-explanatory, and stands alone.

Comment: Also, I referenced the article, for those who felt otherwise.

Comment: The point is that it _is_ overridden in all standard classes (`String`, `Fixnum`, whatnot), which is what the original question was about. So the default implementation in `Object` is rarely used. Like I said: misleading.

Comment: I believe the original question was about all classes, with strings being used as one example. At any rate, all methods perform normally, until overridden - kinda goes without saying...

Comment: I think your example does not clarify the point. See example on strings on my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to "The Ruby programming language" (Flanagan & Matsumoto),
section 4.6.7 page 106

> == is the equality operator. It determines whether two values are equal, according to the lefthand operand's definition of "equal".

And in 3.8.3 page 74:

> Every object has an object identifier, a Fixnum, that you can obtain
>   with the object_id method. The value returned by this method is
>   constant and unique for the lifetime of the object.

So, this works the opposite than Java (surprise to me).